# Is the 'gardening' tag going to be too broad?

Tags: discussion

I felt kind of dumb using the [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening), but I didn't feel too creative.  Similar to the [programming](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/543/do-we-need-a-programming-tag-here) tag on programmers.SE.

Every other question probably ought to have the tag right?

Not sure if there is a [landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscaping) tag, but the same would go for it.

Answer (score 10):

Tags should probably be more specific than [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) unless something is affecting your entire garden (over run with some kind of bug/disease).

Even then you should probably say what type of garden it is, IE [fruit](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruit), [vegetable](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetable), [flowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowers). That way the solution can be more focused than if its just a "garden"

Comment: I don't know if I've ever seen a question on SO with a 'programming' tag...

Comment: [tag:flowers] doesn't make a ton of sense if you are talking about the dirt itself (like I was in [this question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/266/revisions) - I used the gardening tag because it existed, but maybe "garden-beds" would work?)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there's no need for a gardening tag here.  I've re-tagged the existing questions and added [gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening) to the blacklist.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, 'gardening' doesn't tell me what your question is about. And I wouldn't go to the sidebar and click on the "gardening" tag to see a subset of questions, or to try and find a duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes 'gardening' struck me as being too broad as well. However I don't think 'landscaping' is. So far landscaping questions are in a minority.